# Binded styles are making entire page jumping (scrolling)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

In my SPA front I have 580 height `div` which contains 9 smaller divs (about 190px height). Parent div has `overflow: hidden` so I see only 3 elements at one time. Every 5 sec I'm changing styles - I'm adding negative `margin-top`, so it looks like they scroll up and new 3 comes from down.

```
<div class="most__popular"
     v-for="n, i in articles" :key="n.id"
     :style="{margin: sliderMargin[i]}">
```

-

```
data() {
    return {
        articles: [],
        errors: [],
        step: 0
    }
},
mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.step = (this.step + 1) % 3;
    }, 5000);
},
computed: {
    sliderMargin() {
        const thresholds = [0, 3, 6];

        return this.articles.map((_, i) =>
            `${(i > thresholds[this.step]) ? '10px' : '-190px'} 0 10px 0`
        );
    }
}
```

Where `articles` is just hardcoded data JSON containing 9 records.

It's working fine but when I scroll page a bit so I see only last element (bottom of this 580height parent div) and when it change from third step to first (from 7,8,9 child divs to 1,2,3) it scroll my page down..

I don't want it to affect on entire page, how I can fix this behaviour?

---

**EDIT**

I add [repository demo](https://bitbucket.org/dopeCode/scrolling-issue), to make it runing on your machine:

install GIT and NodeJS (if you don't already have it you probably will not be able to help me)

- clone/download it `git clone https://dopeCode@bitbucket.org/dopeCode/scrolling-issue.git`
- chose this project in bash/cmd `cd path/where/you've/cloned`
- run `npm install` in bash/cmd
- run `npm run dev` in bash/cmd
- go to localhost:8080 in browser

Scroll page a bit so u see only last element of 3 shown.

Comment: Please post a working code example, otherwise it will be difficult to test this.

Comment: I can create demo repository I don't know how I can reproduce component in plunker

Comment: @BT101 share the demo repository url

Comment: @BT101 does your package.json have entries of all the npm packages you have used in this project?  can you comfirm it?

Comment: @divine Yes I have only used vue in this demo project, just clone in, then chose It in bash `cd path/to/it` then use npm install and then npm run dev and it should start automatically on port 8080

Comment: @BT101 are you using "vue-router" npm package in this project? because i can see (<router-link :to=") some features of "vue-router" being used in your project and there are no entries under dependencies for "vue-router". Because of this missing dependency, i get few errors in browser console. Can you validate your package.json?

Comment: That's because I copied code from existing project, I'll push fix at 11/12 o'clock

Comment: @divine but anyway question is about this weird scrolling behaviour which doesn't depends on routing

Comment: @divine I fixed it just changing `<router-link>` to `<div>`.

Comment: It is not scrolling the entire page down in chrome. which browser are you using?

Comment: Please paste your CSS. Probably the problem is in your CSS. You also can link your site to find the problem or paste a jsbin or jsfiddle here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sliding pictures changing the margin-top, this is not a good idea. Margins don't always behave as expected by the developers. It is better to use relative positioning for this kind of purpose.

I changed your code for relative positioning and it is working perfectly. Make the following changes to your **scrollElements.vue** file.

Add **sliderTop** to your computed section.

```
        sliderTop() {
            const scrollStep = 3;
            const itemHeight = 194;

            return this.articles.map((_, i) =>
                `${(i < this.step*scrollStep) ? (-i*itemHeight) : (-this.step*scrollStep*itemHeight)}px`
            );
        }
```

Use **sliderTop** to style section of *most__popular* elements

```
             :style="{top: sliderTop[i]}">
```

Fix following CSS:

```
.most__popular {
    margin: 10px 0;
    transition: 1s top; /*Only top transition is required*/
    position: relative; /*Added relative positioning*/
}
.most__popular__container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 572px; /*Fixed this height*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in your CSS. You have no CSS? I cannot find it in your post.

Please try to use `overflow:hidden` on your container. Also you can insert zero-height div in your website before opertation, positioned to bottom part of your site and remove it after operation. It should prevent scrolling the page during operation.

BTW. Use CSS for sliders. It is possible to create them without JS. Use transitions and animations. 
Did you think about smartphone-friendly website (RWD)?

Comment: You have no CSS? I cannot find it in your post. That's exacly why I added repository demo, anyway problem is fixed by above answer.